# Action Script 3: Karaoke Player - On Replay, music wont start again, only text

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

i have a problem with Action Script 3. I use Flash CS5.

I want to create a little Karaoke Player. It works for the first play, but not for the second.

In the first layer i have my player (music, buttons, etc). With the play button i start the audio (mp3) and the lyrics (text). I call the text as instance (its a sub layer of the main layer).

Problem is, when i complete the song and the text and want to play it again, only the text starts and NOT the music.

How can i load the music, too?

Here is my code:

```
// Musik
var meinSound = new musik ();
var meinSoundKanal = meinSound.play ();
var meinSoundTransform = meinSoundKanal.soundTransform;
meinSoundKanal.stop ();
var soundPosition = 0;

// Play und Pause Button
var buttonZustand = "Play";

this.play_bt.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonAendern);
function buttonAendern (Param) {
    if (buttonZustand == "Play") {
        this.play_bt.gotoAndStop (2);
        buttonZustand = "Pause";
        meinSoundKanal = meinSound.play (soundPosition);
        meinSoundKanal.soundTransform = meinSoundTransform;
        this.textanimation.play();
    } else {
        this.play_bt.gotoAndStop (1);
        buttonZustand = "Play";
        soundPosition = meinSoundKanal.position;
        meinSoundKanal.stop();
        this.textanimation.stop();
    }
}

// Volume Button
var volumeZustand = "An";

this.volume_bt.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, volumeAendern);
function volumeAendern (Param) {
    if (volumeZustand == "An") {
        this.volume_bt.gotoAndStop (2);
        volumeZustand = "Aus";
        meinSoundTransform.volume = 0;
        meinSoundKanal.soundTransform = meinSoundTransform;
    } else {
        volumeZustand = "An";
        this.volume_bt.gotoAndStop (1);
        meinSoundTransform.volume = 1;
        meinSoundKanal.soundTransform = meinSoundTransform;
    }
}

// Stop Button
this.stop_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, LiedStoppen);
function LiedStoppen (e) {
    meinSoundKanal.stop();
    play_bt.gotoAndStop(1)
    this.textanimation.gotoAndStop(1)
}

// Lautstärkeregler
var bewegungsRaum=new Rectangle(361,357,168,0);

this.regler_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, halten);

function halten(Parameter)
{
    this.regler_bt.startDrag(false, bewegungsRaum);
}

this.regler_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, loslassen);

function loslassen(Parameter)
{
    this.regler_bt.stopDrag();
}


this.regler_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lautRegeln);
function lautRegeln(Param) {
    meinSoundTransform.volume = (this.regler_bt.x -361) / 168;
    meinSoundKanal.soundTransform = meinSoundTransform;
}
```

I hope you can help me :)

Greets

---

UPDATED:

```
// Musik
var meinSound = new musik ();
var meinSoundKanal = meinSound.play ();
var meinSoundTransform = meinSoundKanal.soundTransform;
meinSoundKanal.stop ();
var soundPosition = 0;

meinSoundKanal.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, next_item_handler);
        function next_item_handler(e:Event):void{
         meinSoundKanal.stop();
         soundPosition = meinSoundKanal.position;
    }


// Play und Pause Button
var buttonZustand = "Play";

this.play_bt.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonAendern);
function buttonAendern (Param) {
    if (buttonZustand == "Play") {
        this.play_bt.gotoAndStop (2);
        buttonZustand = "Pause";
        meinSoundKanal = meinSound.play (soundPosition);
        meinSoundKanal.soundTransform = meinSoundTransform;
        this.textanimation.play();
    } else {
        this.play_bt.gotoAndStop (1);
        buttonZustand = "Play";
        soundPosition = meinSoundKanal.position;
        meinSoundKanal.stop();
        this.textanimation.stop();
    }
}



// Volume Button
var volumeZustand = "An";

this.volume_bt.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, volumeAendern);
function volumeAendern (Param) {
    if (volumeZustand == "An") {
        this.volume_bt.gotoAndStop (2);
        volumeZustand = "Aus";
        meinSoundTransform.volume = 0;
        meinSoundKanal.soundTransform = meinSoundTransform;
    } else {
        volumeZustand = "An";
        this.volume_bt.gotoAndStop (1);
        meinSoundTransform.volume = 1;
        meinSoundKanal.soundTransform = meinSoundTransform;
    }
}

// Stop Button
this.stop_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, LiedStoppen);
function LiedStoppen (e) {
    meinSoundKanal.stop();
    play_bt.gotoAndStop(1)
    this.textanimation.gotoAndStop(1)
}

// Lautstärkeregler
var bewegungsRaum=new Rectangle(361,357,168,0);

this.regler_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, halten);

function halten(Parameter)
{
    this.regler_bt.startDrag(false, bewegungsRaum);
}

this.regler_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, loslassen);

function loslassen(Parameter)
{
    this.regler_bt.stopDrag();
}


this.regler_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lautRegeln);
function lautRegeln(Param) {
    meinSoundTransform.volume = (this.regler_bt.x -361) / 168;
    meinSoundKanal.soundTransform = meinSoundTransform;
}
```

---

UPDATED AGAIN :D

```
// Musik
var meinSound = new musik ();
var meinSoundKanal = meinSound.play ();
var meinSoundTransform = meinSoundKanal.soundTransform;
meinSoundKanal.stop ();
var soundPosition = 0;

meinSoundKanal.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, next_item_handler);
    function next_item_handler(e:Event):void{
          var soundPosition = 0; 
          var meinSoundKanal = meinSound.play ();
    }


// Play und Pause Button
var buttonZustand = "Play";

this.play_bt.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonAendern);
function buttonAendern (Param) {
    if (buttonZustand == "Play") {
        this.play_bt.gotoAndStop (2);
        buttonZustand = "Pause";
        meinSoundKanal = meinSound.play (soundPosition);
        meinSoundKanal.soundTransform = meinSoundTransform;
        this.textanimation.play();
    } else {
        this.play_bt.gotoAndStop (1);
        buttonZustand = "Play";
        soundPosition = meinSoundKanal.position;
        meinSoundKanal.stop();
        this.textanimation.stop();
    }
}

// Volume Button
var volumeZustand = "An";

this.volume_bt.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, volumeAendern);
function volumeAendern (Param) {
    if (volumeZustand == "An") {
        this.volume_bt.gotoAndStop (2);
        volumeZustand = "Aus";
        meinSoundTransform.volume = 0;
        meinSoundKanal.soundTransform = meinSoundTransform;
    } else {
        volumeZustand = "An";
        this.volume_bt.gotoAndStop (1);
        meinSoundTransform.volume = 1;
        meinSoundKanal.soundTransform = meinSoundTransform;
    }
}

// Stop Button
this.stop_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, LiedStoppen);
function LiedStoppen (e) {
    meinSoundKanal.stop();
    play_bt.gotoAndStop(1)
    this.textanimation.gotoAndStop(1)
}

// Lautstärkeregler
var bewegungsRaum=new Rectangle(361,357,168,0);

this.regler_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, halten);

function halten(Parameter)
{
    this.regler_bt.startDrag(false, bewegungsRaum);
}

this.regler_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, loslassen);

function loslassen(Parameter)
{
    this.regler_bt.stopDrag();
}


this.regler_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lautRegeln);
function lautRegeln(Param) {
    meinSoundTransform.volume = (this.regler_bt.x -361) / 168;
    meinSoundKanal.soundTransform = meinSoundTransform;
}
```

Comment: Is you project using the CD+G karaoke format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `soundChannel` class to check whether the audio is finished its playing or not.

```
SndChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, next_item_handler);
    private function next_item_handler(e:Event):void{
         //location for next or prev or repeat link.
    }
```

Comment: Hi Benny Geo, thank you so much for your help. I tried it (see my code), but still no luck. Maybe i got something wrong. Thanks again :)

Comment: I tried it again but it does not work. I get no error message, nothing :) see my main post :)

Comment: Where u 've implement the Sound Class to play the audio?

Comment: I have implented the Sound Class in the // Musik part. The first play works, but the second still does not. There is no error message whatsoever. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Can u able to post the class?